# update data in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i'm trying to make a web app that could make a user login and then see their data and change it

i could make user that already login to see and change their data, but that change didn't change the spreadsheet data

can you help me what's wrong?

this is the code

kode.gs

```
function doGet() {
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('LoginPage')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
    .setTitle('Login Page');
  return htmlOutput;
}

function checkLogin(username, password) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J3Zm7oj2Imqgx_8c6H7DWk7WzagTxuzzIRDtTvTDp1U/edit#gid=0');
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var storedUsername = data[i][0];
    var storedPassword = data[i][1];

    if (username === storedUsername && password === storedPassword) {
      var name = data[i][2]; // Assuming name is in the third column
      var phoneNumber = data[i][3]; // Assuming phone number is in the fourth column
      return { isAuthenticated: true, name: name, phoneNumber: phoneNumber };
    }
  }

   return { isAuthenticated: false, name: null, phoneNumber: null };
}
function updateUserData(newName, newPhoneNumber) {
  try {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J3Zm7oj2Imqgx_8c6H7DWk7WzagTxuzzIRDtTvTDp1U/edit#gid=0');
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  // Find the row corresponding to the logged-in user (you may need to modify this logic)
  var usernameColumn = 0; // Change this if needed
  var passwordColumn = 1; // Change this if needed
  var nameColumn = 2; // Change this if needed
  var phoneNumberColumn = 3; // Change this if needed

  var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
  var userRow = -1;

  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][usernameColumn] === username) {
      userRow = i;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (userRow !== -1) {
    // Update the user's name and phone number
    sheet.getRange(userRow + 1, nameColumn + 1).setValue(newName);
    sheet.getRange(userRow + 1, phoneNumberColumn + 1).setValue(newPhoneNumber);
  }}
  catch (error) {
    // Log the error and handle it gracefully
    Logger.log('Error: ' + error);
    // You can return an error message or handle it in some other way here
    return 'Error updating user data: ' + error.message;
  }
}
```

and this is the LoginPage.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Login</h2>
  <form id="loginForm">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required><br>

    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required><br>

    <input type="button" value="Login" onclick="submitForm()">
  </form>

  <div id="userData" style="display: none;">
    <h2>User Data</h2>
    <p id="userName"></p>
    <p id="userPhoneNumber"></p>
    <button id="editName" onclick="editName()">Edit Name</button>
    <button id="editPhoneNumber" onclick="editPhoneNumber()">Edit Phone Number</button>
    <input type="text" id="newName" style="display: none;" placeholder="New Name">
    <input type="text" id="newPhoneNumber" style="display: none;" placeholder="New Phone Number">
    <button id="saveButton" onclick="saveUserData()" style="display: none;">Save</button>
  </div>

  <div id="loginMessage"></div>

  <script>
    function submitForm() {
      var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
      var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
      google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(function(response) {
          if (response.isAuthenticated) {
            document.getElementById('loginMessage').textContent = 'Login successful';
            displayUserData(response);
          } else {
            document.getElementById('loginMessage').textContent = 'Login failed. Please check your credentials.';
            hideUserData();
          }
        })
        .checkLogin(username, password);
    }

    function displayUserData(response) {
      document.getElementById('userName').textContent = 'Name: ' + response.name;
      document.getElementById('userPhoneNumber').textContent = 'Phone Number: ' + response.phoneNumber;
      document.getElementById('userData').style.display = 'block';
    }

    function hideUserData() {
      document.getElementById('userName').textContent = '';
      document.getElementById('userPhoneNumber').textContent = '';
      document.getElementById('userData').style.display = 'none';
    }

    function editName() {
      document.getElementById('userName').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('editName').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('newName').style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById('saveButton').style.display = 'block';
    }

    function editPhoneNumber() {
      document.getElementById('userPhoneNumber').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('editPhoneNumber').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('newPhoneNumber').style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById('saveButton').style.display = 'block';
    }

    function saveUserData() {
      var newName = document.getElementById('newName').value;
      var newPhoneNumber = document.getElementById('newPhoneNumber').value;
      google.script.run.updateUserData(newName, newPhoneNumber);
      document.getElementById('userName').textContent = 'Name: ' + newName;
      document.getElementById('userPhoneNumber').textContent = 'Phone Number: ' + newPhoneNumber;
      document.getElementById('userName').style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById('userPhoneNumber').style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById('newName').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('newPhoneNumber').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('saveButton').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('editName').style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById('editPhoneNumber').style.display = 'block';
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

i have try to use the try and catch but i can't see the log
can you help me please

Answer (score 0):

#### Modification points:

- When I saw your showing script, in the Google Apps Script side, `var username = document.getElementById('username').value;` is used. I think that this might be the reason for your current issue.
- Also, I think that in your situation, it might be required to also check the values of `username` and `password`.
- In your script, I think that the error message can be seen using `withSuccessHandler`.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

##### Google Apps Script side:

```js
function doGet() {
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('LoginPage')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
    .setTitle('Login Page');
  return htmlOutput;
}

function checkLogin(username, password) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J3Zm7oj2Imqgx_8c6H7DWk7WzagTxuzzIRDtTvTDp1U/edit#gid=0');
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var storedUsername = data[i][0];
    var storedPassword = data[i][1];
    if (username === storedUsername && password === storedPassword) {
      var name = data[i][2]; // Assuming name is in the third column
      var phoneNumber = data[i][3]; // Assuming phone number is in the fourth column
      return { isAuthenticated: true, name: name, phoneNumber: phoneNumber };
    }
  }
  return { isAuthenticated: false, name: null, phoneNumber: null };
}

// I modiifed the below function.
function updateUserData(obj) {
  try {
    var { username, password, newName, newPhoneNumber } = obj;
    var usernameColumn = 0;
    var passwordColumn = 1;
    var nameColumn = 2;
    var phoneNumberColumn = 3;
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J3Zm7oj2Imqgx_8c6H7DWk7WzagTxuzzIRDtTvTDp1U/edit#gid=0');
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    var range = sheet.getDataRange();
    var data = range.getDisplayValues();
    var index = data.findIndex(r => r[usernameColumn] == username && r[passwordColumn] == password);
    if (index == -1) return "No matched row.";
    var newRow = data[index];
    if (newName) {
      newRow[nameColumn] = newName;
    }
    if (newPhoneNumber) {
      newRow[phoneNumberColumn] = newPhoneNumber;
    }
    sheet.getRange(index + 1, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow]);
    return "Done.";
  } catch (error) {
    // Log the error and handle it gracefully
    Logger.log('Error: ' + error);
    // You can return an error message or handle it in some other way here
    return 'Error updating user data: ' + error.message;
  }
}
```

##### HTML & Javascript side:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Login</h2>
  <form id="loginForm">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required><br>

    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required><br>

    <input type="button" value="Login" onclick="submitForm()">
  </form>

  <div id="userData" style="display: none;">
    <h2>User Data</h2>
    <p id="userName"></p>
    <p id="userPhoneNumber"></p>
    <button id="editName" onclick="editName()">Edit Name</button>
    <button id="editPhoneNumber" onclick="editPhoneNumber()">Edit Phone Number</button>
    <input type="text" id="newName" style="display: none;" placeholder="New Name">
    <input type="text" id="newPhoneNumber" style="display: none;" placeholder="New Phone Number">
    <button id="saveButton" onclick="saveUserData()" style="display: none;">Save</button>
  </div>

  <div id="loginMessage"></div>

  <script>
    function submitForm() {
      var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
      var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
      google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(function(response) {
          if (response.isAuthenticated) {
            document.getElementById('loginMessage').textContent = 'Login successful';
            displayUserData(response);
          } else {
            document.getElementById('loginMessage').textContent = 'Login failed. Please check your credentials.';
            hideUserData();
          }
        })
        .checkLogin(username, password);
    }

    function displayUserData(response) {
      document.getElementById('userName').textContent = 'Name: ' + response.name;
      document.getElementById('userPhoneNumber').textContent = 'Phone Number: ' + response.phoneNumber;
      document.getElementById('userData').style.display = 'block';
    }

    function hideUserData() {
      document.getElementById('userName').textContent = '';
      document.getElementById('userPhoneNumber').textContent = '';
      document.getElementById('userData').style.display = 'none';
    }

    function editName() {
      document.getElementById('userName').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('editName').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('newName').style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById('saveButton').style.display = 'block';
    }

    function editPhoneNumber() {
      document.getElementById('userPhoneNumber').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('editPhoneNumber').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('newPhoneNumber').style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById('saveButton').style.display = 'block';
    }

    // I modified the below function.
    function saveUserData() {
      var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
      var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
      var newName = document.getElementById('newName').value;
      var newPhoneNumber = document.getElementById('newPhoneNumber').value;
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(res => console.log(res)).updateUserData({username, password, newName, newPhoneNumber});
      document.getElementById('userName').textContent = 'Name: ' + newName;
      document.getElementById('userPhoneNumber').textContent = 'Phone Number: ' + newPhoneNumber;
      document.getElementById('userName').style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById('userPhoneNumber').style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById('newName').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('newPhoneNumber').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('saveButton').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('editName').style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById('editPhoneNumber').style.display = 'block';
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

- After you access the updated Web Apps and input the name and the password, when you set `newName` and `newPhoneNumber` and click "Save" button, the new values are put into the cells.
- In this modification, when an error occurs at `updateUserData(obj)` of Google Apps Script, you can see the error message at the console of Browser by `withSuccessHandler(res => console.log(res))`.

#### Note:

- **When you modify the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the details of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

#### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script (Author: me)](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)
- [withSuccessHandler(function)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withSuccessHandler(Function))

Comment: THX dude
that works now my script can't be run in android google chrome any info why?

Comment: @Venuze Management Thank you for replying. From `that works now`, I understood that your issue was resolved. About your new question of `my script can't be run in android google chrome any info why?`, unfortunately, I cannot test your situation. So, I have no information about your new question. I think that this is due to my very poor skill. I deeply apologize for my very poor skill again. In that case, I would like to propose to post it as a new question. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it? I deeply apologize for my very poor skill again.